# How to use CompletableFuture to use result of first Callable task as arg to all subsequent Callable tasks?

Tags: java, executorservice, completable-future, threadpoolexecutor

How to use CompletableFuture to use result of first Callable task as arg to all subsequent Callable tasks?   I have 3 tasks that need to run like so:

1. First blocking task runs and returns a value
2. 2nd and 3rd tasks run asysnchronously with argument supplied from first task and return values.
3. All 3 values summed up as a final result from all of it.

I tried to do this below, but I am stuck on the `.thenApply` clause.

I can't quite get this code to work.  IN the `.thenApply` clause, how do I pass an argument from the object response returned?

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class ThreadPoolTest {

    static ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<SumCalculator> cf =
          CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new SumCalculator(100000), threadPool);
        Integer initialResult = cf.getNow(null).call();
        CompletableFuture<SumCalculator> cf2 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(initialResult)
        .thenApplyAsync((i) -> new SumCalculator(i));
     //  i want to call 2 or more SumCalulator tasks here

        System.out.println("DONE? "  + cf2.isDone());
        System.out.println("message? " + cf2.getNow(null).call());
        threadPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Program exit.");
    }

    public static class SumCalculator implements Callable<Integer> {
        private int n;
        public SumCalculator(int n) {
            this.n = n;
        }
        public Integer call() {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                sum += i;
            }
            Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            return sum;
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE:  I do want to collect the responses from all 3 tasks together at the end of the Futures as a combined result list, perhaps as a stream of Integer values?   In this case, I would want to sum the values.  I am wanting to do this for a performance benefit with multiple threads.

Comment: What happens currently when you execute this code?

Comment: If the first calculation must complete before the 2nd and 3rd can proceed, then you can't start them simultaneously.  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: I was about to write an answer and then you've started spamming edits and changing the question every few minutes. Now it even contains multiple inconsistencies.

Comment: I think I am done.  Was trying to simplify because of another person saying they didn't understand the question.

Comment: @djangofan Yes, I know. But then do it in one (!) big edit. You can even delete and undelete the question and do the edit in-between. Or even better: Write a good, easy-to-understand, without inconsistencies, clear question right before you click on post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
    CompletableFuture<Integer> one =
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new SumCalculator(100000).call(), threadPool);

    CompletableFuture<Integer> two = one.thenApplyAsync(x -> new SumCalculator(x).call(), threadPool);
    CompletableFuture<Integer> three = one.thenApplyAsync(x -> new SumCalculator(x).call(), threadPool);

    Integer result = one.join() + two.join() + three.join();
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: What is `CompletableFuture.allOf(one, two, three);` for? The `join`s are already blocking.

Comment: @akuzminykh my bad, it is a bit weird to compile (and think about) code on the phone; that is not needed indeed.

Comment: Hmm.  Having trouble getting it to work with a POJO rather than an Integer.  Hopefully I figure it out.

Comment: @djangofan "having trouble" is not something I can help you with, as I have no details. may be a new question?

Comment: I figured it out: just didn't label a generic type correctly.  Thanks for your help!